# Run-time error '13': Type mismatch on WorksheetFunction.CountIf when the actual Excel Formula (with similar syntax) works perfectly

Tags: vba, excel

Okay, so in Cell B1 I have the below formula (not an Array formula) which works perfectly in Excel:

```
SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A1:A4,A1:A4))
```

This identifies unique values in a range of cells.
So, if A1 = "A", A2 = "B", A3 = "B" and A4 = "C" the result of this formula is 3.  Which is correct.  However, if I try and replicate the exact same function in VBA as follows...:

```
Range("B1") = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(1 / WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A4"), Range("A1:A4")))
```

I get a "Run-Time error '13':  Type mismatch" error.

**I've narrowed it down to the fact that VBA doesn't like that I'm using a multi-cell Range (ie A1:A4) as oppose to a single cell Range (ie A1) in my CountIf.**

I've already written procedure to accommodate the end result that I'm looking for but it's not as elegant as it would be if I could just get the above to work.  Can anyone enlighten me on what I might be doing wrong or is this simply not possible?

Comment: vba doesn;t like SUMPRODUCT. You might have better success with `application.evaluate(...)` if you properly referen ce the parent worksheets.

Comment: VBA has no issue at all with SUMPRODUCT. It does have an issue with trying to create arrays with simple operators like `/` though! Also, you can't use `Worksheetfunction.Countif` like that - you have to use `Application.Countif`

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I have managed to achieve it VBA:

```
Sub TestMe
    Debug.Print Application.SumProduct(1 / Evaluate("=COUNTIF(A1:A4,A1:A4)"))
End Sub
```

In the `CountIf()` formula in Excel you are using an array formula, pressing  <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd> and it seems that the `WorksheetFunction` cannot replicate it. However, `Evaluate()` does it without a problem.